# Specializing hash class for nested class C++

Tags: c++, templates, hash, namespaces, specialization

The goal is to specialize `std::hash` to work with a subclass called `Node`.

And the relevant class is:

```
template<typename T,
         typename Hash = std::hash<T>,
         typename Pred = std::equal_to <T>,
         typename Alloc = std::allocator<T>>
class disjoint_set
{
public:
    typedef Hash hasher;
    typedef Pred value_equal;
    typedef Alloc allocator_type;

protected:
    class Node;
    unordered_set<Node> table;
    // friend class std::hash; // possible solution

    class Node
    {
    public:
         T data;
         // .......
    };
};
```

I would like to have a hash function as follows:

```
size_t operator()(const Node& node) const { return hasher(node.data); }
```

However, the hasher specialization must be in namespace `std`. One solution I found was to make the specialization a **friend class** but in that case I'm unsure how to access the template arguments of the main class?

Answer (score 1):

You can't specialize on a nested class of a class template - you'd have to write something like:

```
template <class T>
struct hash<typename Outer<T>::Inner> { ... };
```

But that's a non-deduced context, so can never work.

Instead, just pull your `Node` out of `disjoint_set` and make it a standalone class template. At that point, specializing `std::hash` becomes straightforward and using it inside of `disjoint_set` is just as easy.